# juxtaposition of adverbials

Tags: writing-style, adverbials

Consider the following succession of sentences:

1. Everyone struggles.
2. Inevitably everyone struggles.
3. Everyone inevitably struggles.
4. At certain times, everyone struggles.
5. Everyone struggles at certain times.
6. Inevitably everyone struggles at certain times.
7. Everyone inevitably struggles at certain times.
8. At certain times everyone inevitably struggles.
9. Inevitably at certain times everyone struggles.
10. At certain times, inevitably everyone struggles.

Nothing is particularly noteworthy about sentences (2) through (8). The worst objection to sentence (1) would seem to be that it is awkward through being so trivial.

However, sentences (9) and (10) merit some discussion, to my mind, because they feel to me rather awkward stylistically, despite simply being the remaining permutations of the same clauses given in the preceding sentences, despite having the same meaning, and despite being, to my best understanding, consistent with general rules of standard grammar.

It seems that the juxtaposition of the two adverbials expresses a tension between them.

Is this observation an example of any principle that has been systematically characterized?

Comment: The snag about asking questions which ultimately boil down to be largely about style preferences is that there are so many alternatives. Conversationally, "We all struggle at times" sounds way better than the suggestions above to my ears. The inclusion of 'all' makes 'inevitably' redundant; if reinforcement is desired, "There's no getting away from the fact that ..." is what I'd probably use. // In formal use, I'd rephrase entirely.

Comment: How come "Everyone struggles inevitably." has been omitted? Has it been overlooked or is it the case that no  meaning could be assigned to it?

Comment: When you have two or more quantifiers (like _every, all, any, some_) in a clause, you create ambiguities and sometimes ungrammaticalities. Quantifiers (like modals and negatives) have a focus -- some constituent they bind to -- and the placements of quantifiers and their foci in a clause can get very very complex. Complex enough that you might need a house call from a logician.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I think a suitable answer would be any that gives a general term and explanation for the effect you have described, as long as the term is invoked in scholarship, and none is available more specific to the details of the question.

Comment: @LPH: I think it's not needed to illustrate the issue.